# Role of absolute continuity of divergence of BV function in proof of renormalization property

Tags: reference-request, ap.analysis-of-pdes, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

In the paper http://cvgmt.sns.it/paper/436/, the author proves the renormalization property for the flow generated by a vector field $a(t,\cdot) \in BV(\mathbb{R}^N; \mathbb{R}^N)$.

Heuristically, what is the role of one of the key assumptions of the paper: that $\mathrm{div}\, a$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

**Note.** A related question is asked in the post [BV function with absolutely continuous divergence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/327761/bv-function-with-absolutely-continuous-divergence)